# How to make every pool of an Array to be only once Assignable

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, null

Hi I'm a beginner in React. 
I am developing my task and I need to declare an array with null values:

```
this.state = {
  position: [null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null]
};
```

After that I assign some values to this array, but my application does require that every pool can only be changed once.
Regards

Comment: So if `position[1]` was set once, you can't set it again?

Comment: Yes exactly I desire it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the task to *`position` can only be changed from `null` to another value and not to `null` again*, then it gets easy

```
  setPool(i, pool) {
    if(pool === null) return; // prevent that any position gets set back to `null`

    this.setState(({ position }) => {
      if(position[i] !== null) return; // prevent that a pool gets set twice
      return { position: position.map((v, i2) => i === i2 ? pool : v) };
    });
 }
```

Comment: And what is the last line?

Comment: @tekblade it updates the state in an immutable way.

Comment: pool is a value that be assigned to specified array element-in that case i?

Comment: yes. not sure how the other answer should answer your question.

Comment: is there posibility the last line is with mistake?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Proxy` for this

```js
let arr = Array(5).fill(null);
const validator = {
  set:function(obj,prop,value){
    if(obj[prop] !== null) throw "You can't change it again"
    else obj[prop] = value;
  }
}
var p = new Proxy(arr, validator);
p[1] = 2; //the element is successfully changed
console.log(JSON.stringify(p))

p[1] = 3; // changing again throw error.
```